# more aches and pains when I run less

Tags: running, pain

This isn't a "something's broken/hurts please give me medical advice" question, but a "this is weird, is it a known phenomena or do others have similar anecdotal experiences?" question.

I've been running consistently for a while now and before races, or in inclement weather, I run fewer miles and have less strenuous exercises. What I've found is I can *hurt and ache more* during the taper before a race. Which is just so weird.

I'll have a pain in my thigh, my calf will feel off during an easy run, lying down my feat hurt. I have random pains while running but it almost seems worse when I run less.

Is this common? Known? Written about? Indicative of anything?

Thanks for the time.